# XCode4 Declare variables using interface builder

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, iboutlet

It is the general way of implementing/connecting views using viewControllers ( as follows ).

1. Declare IBOutlet variables in .h file of your view controller.
2. Open .xib of your view controller.
3. tap on Files Owner & then connect accordingly.

I want to do in reverse mode ( For XCode4 )

1. I will give a name using Interface builder ( XCode 4 )
2. Then save .xib file.
3. .h file of that view controller will be automatically updated with Outlet Variables

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want do declare your variables through the embedded Interface Builder you need to open your header file in the assistant. You'll find it in the upper right corner. Should be the middle button of those three...

Next you select your Hader-File if it's not opened yet and then connect your Outlets to the place you wish in the Header-File.

Comment: Is it a new feature in XCode4 or It was there in XCode 3?

Comment: This is a new solution in Xcode 4, but it was already possible in Xcode 3 to create variables and then write and merge the Header-File.

Comment: But in XCode3 - It was bit complex or having more steps as compare to this one, Isn't it ? Nice feature. I was not aware of this feature. Great, Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, in Xcode3 it was more complicated and needed much more time as if you did it manually... //Would be great if you accept my answer ;-)